# Как сделать кросбраузерный градиент из тонких полосок в псевдоэлементе?

Tags: css, градиент, linear-gradient

САБЖ: Есть псевдоэлемент на body, в котором находится градиент с 3 тонкими вертикальными полосками красного цвета.

```css
:root{
  --light: red;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0px, 0px);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1320px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #111;
  border-left: 1px solid #111;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent calc(25% - 1px), var(--light) calc(25% - 1px), var(--light) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent calc(50% - 1px), var(--light) calc(50% - 1px), var(--light) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent calc(75% - 1px), var(--light) calc(75% - 1px), var(--light) 75%, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 100% 1px;
}
```

ПРОБЛЕМА:
Однако, он то не работает в Хроме/Сафари или в Фаерфокс, то вообще не появляется на экране.
Кроме того при сужении окна, в Фаерфоксе, все линии сливаются в одну.

ВОПРОС:
Как переписать код на кросбраузерный, чтобы градиент отображался?

Comment: @andreymal, приношу извинения. Выправлено

Comment: Не появляется, потому что у body `height: 100%` не работает. Сделайте 100vh